# forward referencing in a listof tocloft; from the text to the content line

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, cross-referencing, tocloft

I use `tocloft` extensively to extract things like priorities and actions; and make cross referenced todo style indexes in the Appendix. Which then nicely reference the place in the main text where they where `\addcontentsline`-ed.

Now I'd like to be able to also have a (forward) reference going from the place in the main text to the specific contentline in the `\listof...`

How is that best done ? The `\phantomsection`
 in the `\addcontentsline{}` is not giving the effect I expected; the reference is always to the top of the section/appendix.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[pdftex,colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{xargs}

\newlistof{ex}{ex}{}
\addtolength\cftexnumwidth{2em}

\newcommandx{\refine}[2]{%
        \refstepcounter{ex}%
    \addcontentsline{ex}{ex}{\protect\numberline{ex-\theex} %
        \protect\phantomsection%
        \protect\label{ex-\theex} ``\emph{#1}'': #2 }%
    #1\emph{[\ref{ex-\theex}]}%
}

\begin{document}

Something about \refine{Mary}{Name under discussion. Have considered Fred.} needs to be said.

Appendix

\listofex

\end{document}
```

So in above example - have the Mary in the main text have a reference/hyperlink to the content line in the appendix - as opposed to all the refs in the `\listofex` being identical - and pointing to the section of the appendix.

Any and all suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: Your example works as expected, with content in the text jumping to the correct location in the `\listofex`, and every entry in the `\listofex` jumping back to the correct location in the main text. Each change though has to be accompanied by 3 compilations.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the O.P. apparently forgot the use three compilation runs to get the labels and hypertargets correctly. (The example provided by the O.P. works!)